# Trying to use expo-location to update location in background but it doesn't work

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to update my app location in the background and see it in the console log when I change the android emulator location, but it doesn't work. When I start the app, it shows the following error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Map o.e.c.a.d.getOptions()' on a null object reference]
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:103:50 in promiseMethodWrapper
at node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/build/NativeModulesProxy.native.js:15:23 in moduleName.methodInfo.name
at node_modules/expo-location/build/Location.js:164:10 in startLocationUpdatesAsync
at node_modules/expo-location/build/Location.js:162:7 in startLocationUpdatesAsync
at src/app/services/LocationService.ts:57:10 in startBackgroundServiceAsync
at src/app/services/LocationService.ts:56:2 in startBackgroundServiceAsync
at src/app/hooks/useLocation.ts:16:12 in <anonymous>
```

I'm using expo v42.0.1, expo-location v12.1.2 and expo-task-manager v9.2.2.
I have also added "permissions": ["ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"] to the app.json.

*App component file (main)*

```
...imports

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const locationService = new LocationService();
    (async () => {
      await locationService.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      await locationService.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
      await locationService.startBackgroundServiceAsync();
    })();
  }, []);

  return <View/>
}
```

*Location Service file*

```
...imports

const backgroundLocationTask = 'background-location-task';

defineTask(backgroundLocationTask, async ({ data, error }: any) => {
  console.log('Background Location');
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  const { locations } = data;
  const latitude = locations[0].coords.latitude;
  const longitude = locations[0].coords.longitude;
  console.log(latitude, longitude);
});

export class LocationService {
  async requestForegroundPermissionsAsync() {
    const { status } = await requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted')
      throw new Error('ForegroundLocationPermissionNotGranted');
  }

  async requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync() {
    const { status } = await requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted')
      throw new Error('BackgroundLocationPermissionNotGranted');
  }

  async startBackgroundServiceAsync() {
    await startLocationUpdatesAsync(backgroundLocationTask, {
      accuracy: LocationAccuracy.High
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: anyone! solved this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code and it worked properly. See if it can help you

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
      StyleSheet,
      StatusBar,
      Platform,
      SafeAreaView,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Text,View,
    } from "react-native";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import { Alert } from "react-native";
    
    
    const STATUSBAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === "os" ? 20 : StatusBar.currentHeight;
    const LOCATION_TRACKING = 'location-tracking';
    var l1;
    var l2;
    const onPress = async () => {
      let getForeground = await Location.getForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (getForeground.status !== "granted") {
        let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== "granted") {
          Alert.alert("Permission to access location was denied");
          return;
        } else {
          let backgroundPermissions = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
          if (backgroundPermissions.status == "granted") {
            console.log("Permission to access location granted");
          }
        }
      }
    };
    
    TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TRACKING, async ({ data, error }) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("LOCATION_TRACKING task ERROR:", error);
        return;
      }
      if (data) {
        const { locations } = data;
        let lat = locations[0].coords.latitude;
        let long = locations[0].coords.longitude;
    
        l1 = lat;
        l2 = long;
        origin = lat+','+long;
        console.log(`${new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString()}: ${lat},${long}`);
      }
    });
    
    const UserLocation = () => {
      const [locationStarted, setLocationStarted] = React.useState(false);
    
      const startLocation = () => {
        startLocationTracking();
      };
      
      const startLocationTracking = async () => {
        await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TRACKING, {
            accuracy:Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
            timeInterval: 2000,
            distanceInterval: 0,
            foregroundService: {
                    notificationTitle: "BackgroundLocation Is On",
                    notificationBody: "We are tracking your location",
                    notificationColor: "#ffce52",
                  },
        });
        const hasStarted = await Location.hasStartedLocationUpdatesAsync(
            LOCATION_TRACKING
        );
        setLocationStarted(hasStarted);
        console.log('tracking started?', hasStarted);
        
      };
    
      const stopLocation = () => {
        setLocationStarted(false);
        TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(LOCATION_TRACKING)
            .then((tracking) => {
                if (tracking) {
                    Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TRACKING);
                }
            })
      }
    
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              height: 50,
              width: 300,
              backgroundColor: "red",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
            onPress={onPress}
          >
            <Text>Enable background location</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={{}}>
              {locationStarted ?
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={stopLocation}>
                      <Text style={styles.btnText}>Stop Tracking</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  :
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={startLocation}>
                      <Text style={styles.btnText}>Start Tracking</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                }
                
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        paddingTop: STATUSBAR_HEIGHT,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      },
      btnText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        color: 'white',
        paddingHorizontal: 30,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginTop: 10,
    },
    });
    
    export default UserLocation
```